# Use pymongo in django directly

Tags: django, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine, django-mongodb-engine

I am building a website using Django and MongoDB. There are 2 popular API framework that we can use to connect `Django` and `MongoDB`, one is `mongoengine` and the other is `django-mongodb-engine`.

Because the latest `mongoengine` is not supported Django anymore [Document](http://docs.mongoengine.org/django.html), and `django-mongodb-engine` needs another `django-nonrel` package which makes the development environment a little bit complicate.

I am wondering, if I could use `Pymongo` to connect `Django` and `MongoDB` directly.

Is there anyone who have the same experience that could share? and how to set the db in `setting.py` in Django to make the db public?

Comment: Mongoengine 0.9 can be an option with Django ( given that you do not have dependence on some feature/enhancement in 0.10 release). Read [docs](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/apireference.html) for connecting to mongodb.

Answer (score 8):

you may use `pyMongo` like below code

```
from pymongo import MongoClient


class MongoConnection(object):

    def __init__(self):
        client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
        self.db = client['database_name']

    def get_collection(self, name):
        self.collection = self.db[name]
```

we create a connection as per our need.

```
class MyCollection(MongoConnection):

    def __init__(self):
       super(MyCollection, self).__init__()
       self.get_collection('collection_name')

    def update_and_save(self, obj):
       if self.collection.find({'id': obj.id}).count():
           self.collection.update({ "id": obj.id},{'id':123,'name':'test'})
       else:
           self.collection.insert_one({'id':123,'name':'test'})

    def remove(self, obj):
        if self.collection.find({'id': obj.id}).count():
           self.collection.delete_one({ "id": obj.id})
```

Now you just need to call like below.

```
my_col_obj = MyCollection()
obj = Mymodel.objects.first()
my_col_obj.update_and_save(obj)
my_col_obj.remove(obj)
```

Answer (score 2):

I am currently working on a very similar problem.

You are right, `mongoengine` does not support Django, but, as far as I know, `pymongo` does not support it too. At least `mongoengine` have plans to support it some day. If you are familiar with Django, it has model-like things - documents. They are easy to work with - this is actually a full working ORM. You don't get that with `pymongo` and if you are going to build a large, reusable application, you will end up writing ORM yourself or have spaghetti code. This was the reason for me to use `mongoengine`.

In your `settings.py` you should include this code:

```
from mongoengine import connect
connect('your_database')
```

If you still want to use `pymongo` for some reason, your code should look like this:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient()
```

Comment: Thank you. If I use the pymongo solution, will the `client` be the global variable in Django?

Comment: it is completely up to you to decide - I assume that you are going to use it for some low level stuff and it depends on what you need

Answer (score 0):

Basically it should be possible to create a custom db class with implemented `MongoClient()` no matter what web framework you chose to work with, Flask, FastAPI, Django. 2nd answer is pretty good example code for this ;)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).