# How to connect Django ORM to mongo atlas?

Tags: django, mongodb, mongodb-atlas, djongo

I am trying to connect my django instance to a mongo db cluster using django. I have checked from various sources and the way it is getting closer to work is:

- Install dnspython
- Have the following `DATABASES` dict in `settings.py`

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'NAME': 'test',
        'HOST': 'mongodb+srv://mongo_usr:' + urllib.parse.quote('mypassword') + '@domain_assigned.mongodb.net/test?ssl=true&ssl_cert_reqs=CERT_NONE&retryWrites=true',
        'ENFORCE_SCHEMA': False
    }
}
```

It truly finds the endpoint but I am getting a weird error:

`pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: connection closed,connection closed,connection closed`

has anyone fixed this before?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use pymongo in django directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31552914/use-pymongo-in-django-directly)

Comment: You can make the connection using pymongo, no need of using djongo

Comment: Indeed, but in such case don't you bypass the orm completely?

Comment: are you using djongo in production environment ?

Comment: For now it is in dev, but the ultimate goal is to move it live. It is about a personal project, not a corporate one. I wouldnt try it on production for my company. Not because it is not of high quality but because I am afraid of one man projects (there are many contributors though)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just setup Djongo and MongoDB Atlas with the following:

```
DATABASES = {
        'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'NAME': '<db name>',
        'HOST': 'mongodb+srv://<db username>:<db password>@....mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true',
        'USER': '<db username>',
        'PASSWORD': '<db password>',
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Make sure you have Djongo installed. "pip install djongo".

Comment: Pretty similar to mine...though the devil hides in details. I will check and let you know

Comment: I have applied the template you posted, added my credentials and values and is still not working. I have also tried with escaping my password. Still nothing. 

Just to make sure, could you post a screenshot of where the db name is seen, to verify I am not putting a wrong dbname (and maybe I am putting the cluster).

Thanks

Comment: any idea on how to connect it using *mongoengine* ??

Comment: I was not able to get this method to work - even with an atlas generated password without funky characters. I noticed djongo was uninstalling my django installed build of 3.1 and installing django to 3.0.5 - not sure if this is the cause but method described by Nagarjun worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

Install djongo package using 
`pip install djongo`.

Make sure you import following module:

```
import urllib
```

Setup database settings.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'NAME': '<db_name>',
        'HOST': "mongodb+srv://<db_username>:" +
                urllib.parse.quote_plus("<db_password>") +
                "@........mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&ssl=true&ssl_cert_reqs=CERT_NONE&w=majority",
    }
}
```

Substitute db_username, db_name and db_password with your credentials.

Also edit the host name given by Mongo Atlas.

Answer (score 6):

Got this working without any hack as follows:

1. Install `pip install dnspython`.
2. Update settings.py with the following,

```
'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'NAME': '<dbname>',
        'CLIENT': {
            'host': "mongodb+srv://<username>:" + quote_plus('<password>') + "@<cluster-name>.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
        },   
    }
```

3. Run `python manage.py makemigrations`
4. Run `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: I tried the checked answer but had lots of difficulties. After an hour of debugging, I tried this and it worked first go! I already had dnspython for other projects. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

Simplest and correct solution:

Step 1: Install djongo and dnspython

> pip install djongo
>
> pip install dnspython

Step 2: Changes in settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
"default": {
    "ENGINE": "djongo",
    "CLIENT": {
        "host": "mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@<cluster_name>.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority",
        "username": "<username>",
        "password": "<password>",
        "name": "<database_name>",
        "authMechanism": "SCRAM-SHA-1",
    },
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to connect to mongo atlas with djongo by using the snippet from @Market Ahead [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55560416/163085)

It looks like they dont want the password to have weird characters inside. In such case, even escaping is not working optimally.

Comment: You accepted your own answer referencing the actual answer

Answer (score 0):

After editing your DB's settings.py, go to your env lib and make these changes in pymongo/mongo_client.py

```html
HOST = "mongodb+srv://<Username>:<password>@cluster0-gbdot.mongodb.net/<databaseName>?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
```

Answer (score 0):

For djongo version 1.3.6 this worked for me:

```
DATABASES = {
"default": {
    "ENGINE": "djongo",
    'ENFORCE_SCHEMA': False,
    "NAME": "<db_name>",  # name of your DB which you want to access
    "CLIENT": {
        'host': 'mongodb://<username>:<password>@<db_url>:<port>',  # your db_url if not hosted then localhost
        'port': <port>,  # port e.g. 27017
        'username': '<username>',
        'password': '<password>',
        'authSource': 'admin',  # set your db auth_source if you know
        'authMechanism': 'SCRAM-SHA-1'  # set your auth_mechanism if you know
# add other settings as per your requirements
    }
}
```

}